# “Double use” of a4paper (geometry/KOMA)?

Tags: koma-script, paper-size, geometry, preamble, package-options

In my preamble, should I give the `a4paper` option just once or twice, i. e. once for the KOMA-script document class (`scrartcl`) and once for `geometry`? Is this redundant or does `scrartcl` need the option for the calculation of the type area (or something else)?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
```

Lately, I have just used

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
```

and I haven’t had any adverse effects. Still, it seems a little strange to me not to pass any “size options” to the document class. But is this the “right way” to go?

By the way, I am using XeLaTeX to typeset.

Comment: all optional arguments specified at the document class are passed to _all_ packages. So the `a4paper` for geometry is redundant

Comment: Why do you use Geometry at all? Isn't it totally superfluous if you use scrartcl, and therefore, typearea?

Comment: That’s something I asked myself as well, when I was writing the question. I think I once saw a template making use of it and then thought it to be good practice. But actually … it probably is superfluous. Does anyone know whether `geometry` is better than `typearea`? (Because apparently I am overwriting its settings as *Ulrike Fischer* pointed out.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using `geometry` you are overwriting the settings from `typearea` so the class doesn't need the option (btw `a4paper` or more precisely the option `paper=a4` is the default anyway).

I personally don't use global options if possible to avoid unwanted side effects on packages. With local options it is easier to control which package gets which option.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know,  global options, specified with the document class, will be passed down to the packages. So your global specification regarding paper size or language like `ngerman` for example will be used by any packages, where you could use this option too, like `babel` or `csquotes`.

Regarding `a4paper`in special, I think the KOMA-Classes already use this paper format by default, so it is not neccessarily needed as an option to the `documentclass`.

> The option a4paper could be omitted with scrreprt, since this is a predefined setting
>   for all KOMA-Script classes. [See the KOMA Guide on p. 30.](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)

So, in your case, you should be able to omit the `a4paper` alltogether without negative consequences, as it is already "preloaded".